# differents loading html in opera with Internet explorer

Tags: asp.net

I have been design a site it is started nice in explorer but it is not nice I mean it different from IE (borders and alignments) in opera and some other browser. How I can set my site to load by all browser ? 
I use asp.net to design pages. net framework 4.0

Comment: Can you specify, what "not nice" means? Does the page just look different in opera? Or what part doesn't work correctly?

Comment: yes it is completely different not nice mean border and spaces alignments are different from when site loads by IE

Comment: Do you know something about HTML browser campatabilities? Not all browsers follows HTML w3c specification. So for correct display pages you should read somthing about HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach the design slightly differently, and design/code the XHTML/CSS for Opera/Firefox/Safari etc first, and then see how it displays in IE. Possibly implementing conditional stylesheets to manage IEs quirks.